# Have multiple before/after comparisson sliders

Tags: javascript, laravel, slider, comparison

Hello im trying to loop a Before/after image slider, but im having problems, with a single Slider it works fine but as soon as i put it through a foreach loop i only have one working, suppose it's a javascript "problem"?

**HTML**

```
@foreach ($studyCases as $studyCase)
<div id="comparison">
    <figure style="background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/photoshop-face-before.jpg); ">
    <div id="divisor" style="background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/photoshop-face-after.jpg);"></div>
    </figure>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="slider" oninput="moveDivisor()">
  </div>

@endforeach
```

**Javascript**

```
var divisor = document.getElementById("divisor"),
slider = document.getElementById("slider");
function moveDivisor() { 
    divisor.style.width = slider.value+"%";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that problem is that you're referring to only one element when you're trying to execute `moveDivisor` function. Javascript finds only one element when getting by id from document as id property should be unique in whole HTML. You can try to build your HTML structure adding i.e. loop indexes to your ids like that:

```
id="divisor-{{ $loop->index }}"
```

Then you can pass element id to function in `onclick` in the same way to let `javascript` know which slider you're trying to reach:

```
oninput="moveDivisor('divisor-{{ $loop->index }}')"
```

Last step is to modify your `javascript` to make it find proper element:

```
function moveDivisor(elementId) { 
    var divisor = document.getElementById(elementId);
    divisor.style.width = slider.value+"%";
}
```

Comment: Yep you're completely right!! I was thinking about creating a for loop inside javascript, but your answer is way more correct. The elementId parameter will mirror the the $loop->index via the oninput="moveDivisor('divisor-{{ $loop->index }}')": Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: @RicardoPires You're welcome :) I'd appreciate if you could accept my answer.

Comment: I would love to, but apparently i cant vote, im not a "level 15 user" 

Comment: Can't you accept answer? It is not connected to voting, it's tick placed under downvote arrow.

Comment: Done buddy thnx!